# Please modify the javascript function if it finds no querystring

Tags: javascript, query-string

I want to get querystring value by javascript. I am using this function.

```
var qs = (function (a) {
if (a == "") return {};
var b = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    var p = a[i].split('=');
    if (p.length != 2) continue;
    b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));

}
return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```

It works well. But if there is no querystring value in the url, if is an error.
I want to modify it as if it find querysting value return it.

If there is no query string value then return word "Natural"

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top you could write:

```
if (a == "") return "Natural";
```

But that is really weird you would want to do this.

Comment: I have tired it but still it returns "undefined"

Comment: I use this way: my url is: www.example.com/index.html?keyword=abc I get correct value "abc" using   var keyword = qs["keyword"]; But if url is www.example.com/index.html  then it don't work.

Comment: Yes it is working on  jsfiddle.net/zdRvL but if you change the last line alert(qs["keyword"]) then it return undefined.

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal of course, because the query string is empty, there is no keyword value

Comment: is there any way capture it. if value for keyword is null then it return word 'natural'

Comment: `var value = qs["keyword"] || "Natural";`